# check if list of mp4/m4v/mkv files has subtitles

Tags: mp4, subtitle, mkv

i have list of about 230 video files (mp4, m4v and mkv), i want to make sure that all of them has english subtitles. is there an easy way to check it? (instead of open each 1 to see if it contains englifh subtitles).

Thanks

Comment: ffprobe can be used to detect the different streams in a file. Try something like `ffprobe FILE -show_streams -select_streams s 2>&1|grep language=eng` This command outputs the details of all the subtile streams in the file (the select s), and then the grep command filters for streams where the language is English

Comment: i tried to enter the folder where the video files are (in the terminal), pasted the code, change the s to a name of a file in this folder and it showed nothing. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I also tried to build a script (first time) that run on all the files in the folder and using this command `ffmpeg -i file_name -c copy -map 0:s -f null - -v 0 -hide_banner && echo $? || echo $?` on each file. it always return 1 (= no subtitles found) even when it runs on file that i know it has subtitles.

Comment: ok, i succeed building the script, now it shows me which file has subtitles. now i just need to know if the subtitles are in english.